# C# PDF compression / recompress JBIG2 to JPEG

Tags: c#, pdf, itext, compression, jbig2

I have PDF compressed with JBIG2. How can I recompress it to JPEG or any other compression algorithms? 
I want to use open source solution like Itextsharp/PDFSharp or any other c# .net open source project.

Answer (score 0):

You would need to decompress the image data, convert it from 1 bit per component to 8 bits per component, then apply JPEG compression.

**But** it's a bit unusual to convert monochrome images to color.  This should increase the size actually.  JBIG2 is pretty good for many monochrome images, why do you want to use JPEG compression on it?

Comment: Hi Joseph. I have purchased a PDF. NET SDKs that do not support JBIG2. I need to convert PDF JBIG2 to other formats like JPEG or Fax Group 4. How can I decompress JBIG2 ?